# Plotting every 30th file of a list

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have 1000 files and if I want to plot every 30th file. I tried to reach out the simplest way of separating but it does not work because I have sorted files and by the code, it tries to plot every single file.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import rcParams
%matplotlib qt

l = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir('.')) if f.startswith('file')]

maxnum = np.max([int(os.path.splitext(f)[0].split('_')[1]) for f in l])
l = ['file%d.out' % i for i in range(maxnum)]
for i, d in enumerate(l): 
    a = np.loadtxt(d).T 
    num = os.path.splitext(d)[0] 
    plt.plot(a[0][a[5]<=0.000], a[1][a[5]<=0.000], c=cmap.to_rgba(i+1),label=num[-3:], lw=0.75) 
    #idx = np.argwhere(a[0] == 0)
    #plt.colorbar(cmap, ticks = c)
    #print(idx)
#plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1)) 
plt.xlabel('X Axis')
plt.ylabel('Y Axis')
plt.title("Longterm simulation")
plt.show()
```

I want to decrease the amount of shady plotting to have lighter plot e.g. 30 or 40 plots together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you just need to slice `l` with an appropriate `step`, hence replacing this:

```
for i, d in enumerate(l):
```

with this:

```
for i, d in enumerate(l[::30]):
```

will do.